# Permanently add a path to sys.path for Python 2.7 in Mac

Tags: python, pandas, installation-path

My pandas is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, but this path is not included in sys.path of my Apple-provided Python 2.7 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework). How can I permanently (not temporarily) add this path to sys.path?

Comment: Why was it installed there instead of in the site-packages directory of the system Python?

Comment: The clean way here is to switch to a `virtualenv`. Altering the search path for python is rather messy and can lead to quite a number of subtle bugs.

Comment: Look into installing miniconda, which is a python package manager.  You don't want to go down the road of altering your system python.  Here is a link: .http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I moved from Canopy to PyCharm, but the packages are provided by Canopy and thus the path doesn't match

Comment: Thank you for your help. In case of messing up, now I solve this problem by run sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'). This works for my problem.